# Jquery <span> tag problem in mozilla 3.6.1

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mozilla

I'm using `jQuery.post` to print some data I get from a servlet.

```
<div class="Label">
    <span id="result" >Click on Check.</span>      
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            var id =  $("#orderId").val();
            $.post("paidByDiners", { orderId : id},
              function(data) {
                  $("#result").html(data);
              });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On Chrome and IE it works fine. However, in Mozilla the response is `[object XMLDocument]`.

When I'm using Fiddler2 I see the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2011 10:14:11 GMT
Content-Length: 38

This is my response.
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `dataType` of `'text'` to your `$.post` call.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
   var id =  $("#orderId").val();
   $.post("paidByDiners", { orderId : id},
   function(data) {
     $("#result").html(data);
   }, 'text');
   });
 });
```